# Setting multiple tables with the same width

Tags: tables, tabularx

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be an really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Latex. I have multiple tables, all of them containing different character lengths, and what I am looking for is to set them all to the same width

```
 \begin{table} [h]
     \caption {Question} \label{tab:Question} 
     \begin{center}
         \begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr}
            \toprule
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{x}  & Blue \\
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{y}  & Green \\
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{z}  & Red \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Now lets say that I am also using another table that look like this:

```
 \begin{table} [h]
     \caption {Question} \label{tab:Question} 
     \begin{center}
         \begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr}
            \toprule
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{x}  & Just a random text to illustrate \\
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{y}  & my \\
             \multicolumn{2}{l}{z}  & point \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Now when I compile the tables are naturally from different sizes, given the length that is filling every column. So, what I am looking for is to make of the same width size.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Comment: You might be interested in tuing `tabular*` assuming that you want the extra white space that gets added to the narrower table to be evenly distributed over the columns.

Comment: Please also clarify: Why do you declare 8 columns but only use 3 of them? Also, what't the reason for the repeated `\multicolumn{2}{l}` in all rows of the table?

Comment: (1) Are your tables *always* using the same structure? (2) Why not include them in the same table? Is that because you have them in separate floats?

Comment: Instead of `l` columns (which take a variable width equal to the widest element in the column) you can use `p{size}` columns, which always take the specified width and wrap text if it is too long. So for example `\begin{tabular}{p{20mm}p{15mm}p{25mm}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear, if you like to have equal width of columns or tables. Well, in bot cases use of `tabularx` table environment can be handy. FOr example for later case you can write them as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}X}

%---------------- show page layoutdon't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \makegapedcells
\caption {Question} \label{tab:Question-1}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}p{3em} L} % <---
    \toprule
x   &   Blue    \\
y   &   Green   \\
z   &   Red     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
     \caption {Question} \label{tab:Question-2}
    \makegapedcells

\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}p{3em} L} % <---
    \toprule
x   &   Just a random text to illustrate    \\
y   &   my                                  \\
z   &   point                               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

where `0.4\linewidth` determine width of tables. Of course, sensible maximal width of tables is `\linewidth`. Above MWE produce:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

As you can see, that in cases, if the text in cells is longer than prescribed cell's width, text is broken into more lines.